# To check whether input line is word or sentence

Tags: perl

I have a line which can be a single word or sentence. What is the command line to check whether it is a single word or sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

Your input is in `$line`.

Check like below

```
if(chomp($line) =~ /^\w+$/){
    # only a word
} else {
    # It contains multiple words
}
```

Comment: `chomp` should be used to ensure no spaces around `$line`.

Comment: “Won’t” work robustly. :P

Answer (score 0):

Coudln't you just check for spaces in the input line? If it contains a space it's safe to say it's a sentence? Then add some safety checks so it doesn't count when people write something like " word", "word    ", etc. :)

Answer (score 0):

do `split(" ")` and store in Array. If your array more than 1 element so it obviously not a word.